# Translate JS into math (multiple variables defined)

Tags: javascript

I have this code I am trying to translate into maths

```
var Top=1+MonthlyInterestRate;

Top=Math.pow(Top,npr);'

Top=MonthlyInterestRate*Top;

var Bottom=1+MonthlyInterestRate;

Bottom=Math.pow(Bottom,npr)-1;

var MonthlyPayment=(PrincipalBalance*(Top/Bottom)).toFixed(2);
```

My basic problem is that the var 'top' is declared 3 times, so I don't know how to reflect it mathematically.

var bottom is also declared twice, which value will be the final?

the first variable or the second?

Comment: "My basic problem is that the var 'top' is declared 3 times" - No it's not

Comment: I would recommend you reading this: https://javascript.info/variables. Although assigning and declaring is almost same for every language, you should first understand the basics of how variables, const and other things actual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is imperative, instructions are executed from top to bottom. Here's what happens, in order:

1. `Top` equals 1 + `MonthlyInterestRate`,
2. `Top` is set to `Top` to the power of `npr`
3. `Top` is set to `Top` multiplied by `MonthlyInterestRate`
4. `Bottom` equals 1 + `MonthlyInterestRate`,
5. `Bottom` is set to `Bottom` to the power of `npr` minus 1
6. then finally the result of `Top` divided by `Bottom` is multiplied by `PrincipalBalance`

A mathematical equation would be something along the lines of:

where a equals to `PrincipalBalance`, b equals to `MonthlyInterestRate` and c equals to `npr`

[image: equation]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not declared multiple times, but the values are being re-assigned. It will always get the latest one.

You can simply check with:

```js
var variable1 = 10;
variable1 = 20;

var variable2 = 0;
variable2 = 1;

console.log('This is variable 1 value: ', variable1);
console.log('This is variable 2 value: ', variable2);
```